# Endless redirect loop with SSL nginx configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

I configured some basic proxies and then ran certbot. It endlessly redirects me, unfortunately.

I have tried numerous solutions to no avail. Is there something wrong with the other these server blocks are in? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: All of that stuff is managed by Certbot.  Doesn't it have a config of its own?  Shouldn't you provide that one for us to examine?

Comment: As it turns out, it's an issue to do with Cloudflare. The configuration is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com; # managed by Certbot

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out it's something to do with Cloudflare. Thanks for the input, though!